# Importing DocumentReference in Es6

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Classes like DocumentReference, CollectionReference, etc., don't seem to be exported. Is there a way to import these classes?

Answer (score 3):

1. Install firebase if it's not in your package.json:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

2. In the .ts file just import whatever you need:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import DocumentReference = firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
```

3. Use DocumentReference:

```
posts.forEach((doc: DocumentReference) => {
   doc.ref.delete()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

using typescript, this works:

`import * as firebase from "firebase"`

then do
`firebase.firestore().DocumentReference`

Comment: Doesn't work for me too "Unresolved variable DocumentReference "

Comment: Doesn't work for me also. Please see my answer that I came up with after a few hours of researching.